# Bernoulli's equation and internal energy

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy

I have come across an extension of Bernoulli's equation in the **Feynman lectures**.

It has another term in the energy equation describing the internal energy of the fluid:

> $$
> \label{Eq:II:40:17}
> \frac{p_1}{\rho_1}+\frac{1}{2}\,v_1^2+\phi_1+U_1=
> \frac{p_2}{\rho_2}+\frac{1}{2}\,v_2^2+\phi_2+U_2
> $$

It then goes on to say that if the fluid is incompressible, internal energy is equal on both sides $U_1=U_2$, so it is removed.

But how does $U_1=U_2$ reconcile with the fact that a fluid gets colder as the pressure drops and the equipartition theorem which says that energy is shared equally amongst all degrees of freedom.

If static pressure drops then shouldn't internal energy also drop to maintain equipartition?

Why can we make this assumption?

Comment: *"the fact that a fluid gets colder as the pressure drops "* **Fact?** Does water coming out of a tap cool down because it's depressurised? We're not talking about *gases* here.

Comment: hi @Gert thanks for your response , No I was thinking about condensation in a vortex

Comment: Did the reference say "incompressible" or did it say "inviscid?"

Comment: Hi @chestermiller it said Incompressible
"which is the Bernoulli result with an additional term for the internal energy. If the fluid is incompressible, the internal energy term is the same on both sides, and we get again that Eq. (40.14) holds along any streamline. "

Comment: Hi @chestermiller sorry I should add its from lecture 40 "flow of dry water" which deals purely in inviscid flow . Does that help ?

Comment: The equation, as you have written it, is basically the first law of thermodynamics applied an open (control volume) system, for a case in which the system is operating at steady state, and where no heat is being transferred and not shaft work is being done.  It refers specifically to the inlet and outlet streams to the control volume.  For an inviscid incompressible fluid, the temperature would not change so the internal energy would not change.  That's the only thing that makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes the work energy theorem $dU = -W + Q$ would certainly give that result 

$dU = -P.dV + Q=0$  (for no volume change, no heat exchanged and no friction)

but it ignores the pressure change $dP$

$dU = -dP.V + Q$

$dU = (P_2-P_1).V + Q$

I've never understood that. 

and we do see a temperature change in real life don't we ?

Comment: This is a separate question which goes back to the closed system version of the first law of thermodynamics.  I suggest that you submit it as a new Question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47435/discussion-between-quentin-chester-and-chester-miller).

Comment: OK.  But it's bed time for me now.  Be back in the morning.